# Convert natspec into human readable document

Tags: solidity, natspec

How do I convert [Natspec](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Natural-Specification-Format) into something that a human can easily read?

Eg: HTML, Markdown, .PDF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to generate HTML documentation directly from your natspec'd code:

https://github.com/DigixGlobal/doxity

Comment: Unfortunately this library is no longer maintained and support for the latest version of Solidity is not present.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [User Documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Natural-Specification-Format#user-documentation) on the Natspec page, the output is just a JSON blob.

You could feed this JSON output into a conversion tool, e.g.:

- A website such as https://codebeautify.org/json-to-html-converter;
- A command line tool - something like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) would probably work;
- A package for your language of choice, e.g. [`json2html`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json2html) for Python.

Answer (score 1):

I have released a plugin for Hardhat which generates a Vue static site from NatSpec comments: https://github.com/ItsNickBarry/hardhat-docgen