# solidity-doc documentation?

Tags: solidity, documentation

I see something I assume to be akin to javadoc at https://www.npmjs.com/package/solidity-doc and Github at https://github.com/vitiko/solidity-doc.  However, I see no documentation... the closest I get is a line in Github mentioning `/// notation`.

Can anyone tell me where this, or anything similar, may be documented?  From a quick glance at the code, I'm not finding the relevant info.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Natural-Specification-Format

Comment: @RichardHorrocks, thanks, that is what I was looking for.  Please feel free to post as an answer.

Should be in the FAQ, but I didn't see it ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is [Natspec](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Natural-Specification-Format).

If you want to convert this to a more agreeable format, have a look at "[Convert natspec into human readable document](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/convert-natspec-into-human-readable-document)".

Comment: Hmm, I installed doxity and tried to build, without actually having Natspec comments in place yet.  But I hit a bunch of errors that seem more like bitrot (paths not being created, that sort of thing).  Also, parse errors.  I wonder if it's kept pace with Solidity....

Comment: That's annoying. Does it match any of the most recently reported issues? https://github.com/DigixGlobal/doxity/issues (Might be worth raising one if not, though looks like the last commit was 6 months ago, so bitrot wouldn't be surprising... )

Comment: Unfortunately the errors are entirely uninformative:

>⚠️ Error parsing Contract: AbortTest
>⚠️ Error parsing Contract: Common
>⚠️ Error parsing Contract: Debuggable
>⚠️ Error parsing Contract: Econsent
>⚠️ Error parsing Contract: Logger
>⚠️ Error parsing Contract: Migrations
>⚠️ Error parsing Contract: ThrowProxy
>⚠️ Error parsing Contract: strings
>Generating output for 8 contracts...  done!

Comment: So much for obeying linebreaks :).  Anyway, possible the issue is that these use interfaces, and I see issues talking about later solc not being supported.  However, it's still useful to put in the @ tags and be ready for doxity if it ever works, and the source is at least documented this way.

Comment: I hadi no idea whether, after complaining about parsing, I could publish.  If I run publish, I get two complaints.  One is about a missing node.js build.  I don't need it for my Solidity stuff (not yet anyway); I would expect doxity to provide an empty one if it needs it.  The other is trying to rename *scripts/doxity/public* to *docs*.

Comment: NB: adding a placeholder build entry in package.json got around the one complaint, and adding a path to public got it to change from an error to copying an empty directory.  But I still have no documentation.  And the readme and such say nothing about debugging options from what I can see.   Given that they've had open issues about interfaces and such for some time, I have a feeling it's no longer supported and not worth pushing on ...?