# How can I convert natspec into human readable document from Windows and Linux?

Tags: solidity, documentation

How can I convert natspec into human readable document?

Doxity looks good, but I need something for Windows or Linux.

Comment: One of the suggestions in this previous question? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/convert-natspec-into-human-readable-document/28665#28665

Comment: doxity is for macOS

Comment: Yep, understood - I was thinking more of the other answers, given that the output is just JSON.